# following "What's a Creel?"s tutorial: Can't create a IWICBitmapDecoder, in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, direct2d, wic

I've been following "what's a Creel?"'s tutorial for direct 2d. I got to tutorial 8: 'Loading an image'. I didn't have the `spritesheet` object save the pointer to the `Graphics` object as this caused problems with this version of visual studio, so it's passed every time something needing it is called. main point: when I try creating a `IWICBitmapDecoder` with the `wicfactory->CreateDecoderFromFile()` method, I get the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x008C70A7 in Project8.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

and in the Autos I get:

`hr         | E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported.
this       | 0x00c1a5c8 {bmp=0x00000000 <NULL> }    spritesheet *
wicfactory | 0x00000000<NULL>
wicdecoder | 0xcccccccc{...}`

the code being this:

```
#pragma once

#include <wincodec.h>   //include windowscodecs.lib in the linker input
#include "Graphics.h"
#include <d2d1.h>
#include<string>

class spritesheet {
public:

    ID2D1Bitmap* bmp;
    spritesheet() {}

    spritesheet(LPCWSTR file, graphics* gfx) {
        //this->gfx = gfx;
        //bmp = NULL;
        HRESULT hr;
        //create an image factory
        IWICImagingFactory *wicFactory;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
            (LPVOID*)&wicFactory
            );

        //create a decoder
        IWICBitmapDecoder *wicdecoder;
        hr = wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
            file,
            NULL,
            GENERIC_READ,
            WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
            &wicdecoder
            );
        IWICBitmapFrameDecode* wicframe = NULL;
        hr = wicdecoder->GetFrame(0, &wicframe);

        IWICFormatConverter *wicconverter = NULL;
        hr = wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&wicconverter);

        hr = wicconverter->Initialize(
            wicframe,
            GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
            WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
            NULL,
            0.0,
            WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom
            );

        gfx->gettarget()->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
            wicconverter,
            NULL,
            &bmp
            );

        if (wicdecoder) wicdecoder->Release();
        if (wicFactory) wicFactory->Release();
        if (wicconverter) wicconverter->Release();
        if (wicframe) wicframe->Release();

    }

    void init(wchar_t * file, graphics * gfx) {
        //this->gfx = gfx;
        //bmp = NULL;
        HRESULT hr;
        //create an image factory
        IWICImagingFactory* wicFactory;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
            (LPVOID*)&wicFactory
            );

        //create a decoder
        IWICBitmapDecoder* wicdecoder;
        hr = wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
            file,
            NULL,
            GENERIC_READ,
            WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
            &wicdecoder
            );

        IWICBitmapFrameDecode* wicframe = NULL;
        hr = wicdecoder->GetFrame(0, &wicframe);

        IWICFormatConverter *wicconverter = NULL;
        hr = wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&wicconverter);

        hr = wicconverter->Initialize(
            wicframe,
            GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
            WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
            NULL,
            0.0,
            WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom
            );

        gfx->rendertarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
            wicconverter,
            NULL,
            &bmp
            );

        if (wicdecoder) wicdecoder->Release();
        if (wicFactory) wicFactory->Release();
        if (wicconverter) wicconverter->Release();
        if (wicframe) wicframe->Release();

        gfx->rendertarget->DrawBitmap(
            bmp,
            D2D1::RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, 10, 10),        //dest rect
            1.0f,
             D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE::D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR,  //effect for scaling
        D2D1::RectF(0, 0, 10, 10));             //scource rect


}


void draw(graphics *gfx) {
    gfx->rendertarget->DrawBitmap(
        bmp,
        D2D1::RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, 10, 10),        //dest rect
        1.0f,
        D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE::D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR,  //effect for scaling
        D2D1::RectF(0, 0, 10, 10));             //scource rect

    }
};
```

now, just to test things, I did put a `ID2D1Bitmap* bmp;` at the start of each method just to see where things got, but the `wicdecoder` error message just changed to a random place in memory.

Comment: You are not using CoCreateInstance() correctly.  Use the proper interface guid, IID_IWICImagingFactory.  And add error checking so you don't just keep plowing on until it crashes with a random exception.

Comment: could you give an example of how i would use CoCreateInstance() in this context? i'm kind of new to this, and i was wondering how a veteran would implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. the implementation of `CoCreateInstance()` was fine, but there were a few problems with his code, relating to it being outdated.

NOW, before i begin, i must say, this was PARTLY taken from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756686(v=vs.85).aspx

the implementation here still gives no usable implementation of `CoCreateInstance()`, (and also requires you to have the boilerplate code of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370994(v=vs.85).aspx) tutorial. Also, the tutorial's code is from 2008 and the architecture expands the amount of memory the app uses every time you resize the window... but i digress. main point: DON'T use that tutorial's program example as a model for your own programs, but it does give a good example on how to declare/initialize the proper WIC and D2D objects) the Microsoft documentation for DX12 is also out of date, but this is what I will clarify here.

the correct implementation of `CoCreateInstance()`, and the correct way to load an image is:

```
void spritesheet::load(PCWSTR uri, ID2D1HwndRenderTarget * gfx) {

    IWICBitmapDecoder *pDecoder = NULL;
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode *pSource = NULL;
    IWICStream *pStream = NULL;
    IWICFormatConverter *pConverter = NULL;
    IWICBitmapScaler *pScaler = NULL;


    IWICImagingFactory *wicFactory = NULL;

    CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWICImagingFactory,
        (LPVOID*)&wicFactory);

    HRESULT hr = wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
        uri,
        NULL,
        GENERIC_READ,
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
        &pDecoder
        );


    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        // Create the initial frame.
        hr = pDecoder->GetFrame(0, &pSource);
    }


    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

        // Convert the image format to 32bppPBGRA
        // (DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM + D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED).
        hr = wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pConverter);

    }


    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pConverter->Initialize(
            pSource,
            GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
            WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
            NULL,
            0.f,
            WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
            );
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {

        // Create a Direct2D bitmap from the WIC bitmap.
        hr = gfx->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
            pConverter,
            NULL,
            &bmp
            );
    }

    if (pDecoder) {
        pDecoder->Release();
    }
    if (pSource) {
        pSource->Release();

    }
    if (pConverter) {
        pConverter->Release();
    }
}
```

Note:
uri simply being the file name, in a PCWSTR format, declared as `L"name.bmp"` when passing to the function.

the correct way to draw an image is:

```
void spritesheet::draw(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget * gfx, float bx, float by, float rx, float ry, float dx, float dy) {

    D2D1_SIZE_F size = bmp->GetSize();
    D2D1_POINT_2F upperLeftCorner = D2D1::Point2F(dx, dy);

    gfx->DrawBitmap(
        bmp,
        D2D1::RectF(
            upperLeftCorner.x,
            upperLeftCorner.y,
            upperLeftCorner.x + rx,
            upperLeftCorner.y + ry),
        1,
        D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE::D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR,
        D2D1::RectF(
            bx,
            by,
            rx,
            ry)
        );
}
```

Now, the rest of the D2D documentation is not up to date, but still gives you a good example of what's out there to use. Some of the objects don't exist anymore, like `D2D1::Rect` being canned and now you only have: `D2D1::RectF`, nad some of the documentation and tutorials are rather disjointed and untested, but if you dig long enough, you can create a game. just remember to have the x86/x64 redistributeable packages run as part of your installer written in c# (because c++ won't run natively in windows anymore, and c# is half as fast), and your c++ program will run where you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Im tring to do the solution you gave here but no luck still wicFactory is null.

```
D2DGauge* d2dg = reinterpret_cast<D2DGauge*>(args);
HRESULT hr;
bmp = nullptr;

IWICBitmapDecoder *pDecoder = NULL;
IWICBitmapFrameDecode *pSource = NULL;
IWICFormatConverter *pConverter = NULL;

//Creating a factory
IWICImagingFactory *wicFactory = NULL;
CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IWICImagingFactory,
    (LPVOID*)&wicFactory);

MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)wicFactory, NULL, MB_OK);

//Creating a decoder

hr = wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
    filename,
    NULL,
    GENERIC_READ,
    WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
    &pDecoder);

//Read Frame from image
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    // Create the initial frame.
    hr = pDecoder->GetFrame(0, &pSource);
}

//Creating a Converter
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

    // Convert the image format to 32bppPBGRA
    // (DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM + D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED).
    hr = wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pConverter);
}

//Setup the converter
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    hr = pConverter->Initialize(
        pSource,
        GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
        WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
        NULL,
        0.f,
        WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
    );
}
//Use the converter to create an D2D1Bitmap
//ID2D1Bitmap* bmp;
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = d2dg->pRT->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
        pConverter,
        NULL,
        &bmp
    );
}

if (wicFactory)wicFactory->Release();
if (pDecoder)pDecoder->Release();
if (pConverter)pConverter->Release();
if (pSource)pSource->Release();
```

How could I make it not a nullptr?

Comment: This should be asked as a separate question rather than as an answer on an old question.